# Event when a reference is added to a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

Is it possible, in a Visual Studio extension, to receive an event when a new reference is added to a (C#) project?

We've already tried DTE.Events.SolutionItemEvents.ItemAdded and DTE.Events.MiscFilesEvents.ItemAdded events, but they don't seem to get raised.

Comment: You aren't adding a new item or file. Adding a reference modifies the csproj file, it doesn't add anything. Project references are added at the project level so `SolutionItemEvents` won't have anything relevant

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're right, but what should then be used instead?

Answer (score 1):

The [ReferencesEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/vslangproj.referencesevents?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) interface exposes the `ReferenceAdded`, `ReferenceChanged` and `ReferenceRemoved` interfaces. As the docs show, you need to subscribe to these events for each project you want to monitor. This means you should use the `ProjectAdded` and `ProjectRemoved` events from [SolutionEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.solutionevents?view=visualstudiosdk-2019#methods) to monitor project changes too.